# Should you use nofollow links to original sources?

Tags: seo, nofollow, dofollow

When you link to resources or original source, and in particular.... Well, lets just do it this way. I have two particular examples:

**Situation 1**

Say I have a website about boats and have an article about rules and fines for speed of the boat. I'd then link to the official law document from the government. Should such a link be `dofollow` or `nofollow`?

Because in this case, the link is not relevant to the niche at all (boats). But on the other hand, it is a trusted link and can be useful for the readers of the article.

**Situation 2**

Lets take the boat website as an example again. This time I'd have an article about gas and oil for the boat. Now I'd want to link to some websites or companies with good quality oil. It would NOT be sponsored or paid for in any way. Should the link this time be `dofollow` or `nofollow`?

Since in this case, the link is a great resource for users and they would be trusted companies. But again, the particular companies have nothing to do with the niche (boats, while these companies are just general gas and oil companies)

**And also..**

What if you have a lot of outgoing links to a lot of original sources and resources? Because if you would use `dofollow`, wouldn't it come across spammy for Google (even though it would not be spammy and just legit)?

Would it be better to actually limit outgoing links and only use the best links or is it fine to just link a lot of good resources?

Hopefully I explained it properly. I'm really not sure what would be the best practise for SEO and haven't been able to find the answer on such specific questions.

Comment: How is a link to an article about rules and fines for the speed of a boat not about boats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you are overthinking this.

I recommend using **dofollow** for any link that you as the writer endorse as worthwhile, relevant content.

I recommend using **nofollow** for any link that's been submitted by a sponsor or by a site user, or that you otherwise don't endorse as worthwhile or relevant.

> trusted link and can be useful for the readers of the article
>
> would NOT be sponsored or paid for in any way
>
> link is a great resource for users and they would be trusted companies

I recommend you use **dofollow** for all of these links in both Situation 1 and Situation 2. As long as you are linking out to high quality resources that are relevant to the article and relevant to the reader, any concerns over site niche are irrelevant.

---

**Note:** When I say "use dofollow", I don't mean to bother explicitly adding the "dofollow" attribute to your links. What I mean is to just not use "nofollow".

Comment: I'd recommend never using `nofollow`. I'd now use `rel=sponsored` for ads or `rel=ugc` for user generated content.  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/qualify-outbound-links  Nofollow is dead.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I differ a bit in my opinion on that, I would say only bother to do that in situations where it takes no additional effort beyond using `nofollow`, since Google says `nofollow` is "still an acceptable way to flag them". There seems to be no downside to still using `nofollow`, and the only upside to using `sponsored` and `ugc` at this point appears to be to volunteer more data to help Google train their machine learning models, though admittedly that may change in the future so it may be helpful to be ahead of the curve.

Comment: That's fair. In my view ugc and sponsored are much clearer. If you limit yourself to just using them, it's a lot easier to see which links should have them in which link should not.

Comment: Does anyone use explicit dofollows? Is there any reason?

Comment: @Džuris Edited! There's no reason afaik to use explicit dofollow, implicit is always the way to go.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This may be controversial, but I also use `nofollow` on my site when I have to link to a resource where the information is relevant to the reader (sometimes as a [primary source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_source)), but I want to prevent link juice from going to a predatory author/publisher. In that case, neither `sponsored` nor `ugc` really fit, but `nofollow` makes sense to me. For example, in one of my articles I link to a terms of service page on a borderline scammy website, in my discussion of said website.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I agree that I might overthink this, but I felt like it could be spammy if I use all dofollow because I have articles that have many sources (it is quite in depth) so I have a lot of outbound links. Anyways, will just use dofollow then. I appreciate the replies, thank you once again!